# How to sign an apk with 'original' key

Tags: android, apk, apktool

Hey guys I am messing around with apktools but I have a little problem:

I can decompile and recompile an apk but when I want to install it on my device I get an error that it couldn't be installed.

I replaced the resources.arcs of the old apk with the new one but I get the same error.

I then resigned the apk and can install it on my device, but before I can install it i have to uninstall the original app on my phone, since an app with the same package but different key exists on my phone.

Is there a way I can modify an apk and use the old key of it, so I can install the modified app without uninstalling the 'old' version of it?

Comment: Is it your app? Do you have the key which was used to originally sign it?

Comment: No its not my app :) I want to modify a game, but dont want to lose the savestates

Comment: Sorry, then, you're out of luck. Allowing what you suggest would be a major security hole. As @GrahamBorland said, you would need the original keys used to sign the app.

Comment: But how is Lucky Patcher doing it then, for example? oO If I backup an apk with it I can overwrite the old app.

Comment: Did you try with `--copy-original`? Check faq uere: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/#faq (There is no META-INF dir in resulting apk. Is this ok? section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* sign an unsigned APK with a different key from the original, but you will not be able to upload it to the Play Store, nor will you be able to install it on a device that has the same app installed **unless the package name (application ID) has been changed**.

The Play Store doesn't allow two apps with the same application ID to be uploaded, that are signed with different keys. In addition, the Play Store doesn't allow uploading an app with the same application ID, signed with the original key, unless the version is higher than the one currently on the store.

> Is there a way I can modify an apk and use the old key of it [to sign the app]

Not unless you have access to the original key.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short : no, you can't. In order to sign an app (or sign anything, in fact) you need a private key. In your case, the original developer's private key, the one he used to sign the app. Unless he gives you access to it, there's no way you can get it which implies there's no way you can sign your modified app.

If it was possible, imagine the problems it would cause. I could take  the Gmail app, add a malware, sign it and pretend to be Google, causing users to trust that i am Google. This would be terrible.

Answer (score 0):

If the devices is rooted, its possible to install after messing with luckypatcher. Or backup app data -> uninstall -> install -> restore app data